# Codebehind plugin have access path as .action?

Tags: java, json, struts2, dmi, struts2-codebehind-plugin

Can I able to access method as action in Struts 2 with Codebehind plugin? Since there is no `struts.xml` file and its works as `action!method` in the URL.

Just I'm wondering to access a method

How to use Struts tag on class?

```
"@Action(name="action"), <s:url action="action" method="method" />
```

**Class :**

```
@Action(name = "JSONexample")
@Result(name="success",type=JSONResult.class,value="",params={"root","List"})
public class PartAction extends ActionSupport {

public String JSONexample{
-----
return SUCCESS;
}

public String readxml { }
}
```

if I access below method on submit button click , will I get the JSON data?

```
 $.getJSON('ajax/sayHi.action', formInput,function(data)
```

So i can access action in URL as

`localhost:7001/Sample/JSONmethod.action`

to get the JSON data ?

Comment: The codebehind plugin is deprecated; please consider using convention or rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as [Codebehind Plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/codebehind/) doesn't support actions on methods you need to use [Convention Plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/convention/) then use convention annotation `@Action` on method you want to be your action then you don't need `!` explicit mapping.

If you continue to use the Codebehind Plugin, then you have to use [Dynamic Action Invocation (DMI)](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration.html#dynamic-method-invocation) to call the method other than mapped to your action.

Another time had to reread you question, it seems you want to access the action that has not mapping to the method other that `execute`:

1. It isn't supported by the codebehind plugin;
2. You have not mapped it via `struts.xml`. In this case the answer would be  - no, you can't. But you can always use `execute` method!

If you continue with using of DMI better use `s:url` tag to construct the URL and use the `method` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for reply.What is name attribute for @Action? like @Action(name = "") ?

Comment: Like `@Action(name="action"), <s:url action="action" method="method" />`

Comment: Okay , Will try conversion. Its very hard working in codebehind.One more last question, So no way to access action " $.getJSON('ajax/sayHi.action', formInput,function(data) " like this ? Method updated in question section.

Comment: No, not like that, I reviewed the code of codebehind plugin at first I thought It should, because you can do this with xml, but unfortunately it's looking only for annotation on class, not on method.

Comment: I mean you can use $.getJSON but you should put annotation on class and name it name="sayHi", the action name should be the same in url and annotation attribute.

Comment: How to use struts tag url in action class ?

Comment: Just place it above the class definition.

Comment: @Action(name="action"), <s:url action="action" method="method" />
@Result(name="success",type=JSONResult.class,value="",params={"root","List"})
public class PartAction extends ActionSupport { like this ? How it will accept tag syntax in class ?

Comment: No, that syntax is incorrect, s:url tag is used in jsp not in java